# Phone numbers in jQuery Mobile

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mobile, jquery-mobile

I wrote a basic mobile directory search for work.  When I apply the jQuery Mobile code to the results page it no longer allows my android device to "tap" on the phone number (formatted as xxx-xxx-xxxx) and have it pre-fill the dialer on the phone.  Without the jQM it works fine.  Am I missing something, do I have to tag the phone number a certain way in order to get the phone to recognize it again?  The jQM applies the "data-role=listview" to my unordered list and nested unordered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this page that talks about formatting various link types:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/docs/pages/link-formats.html

Comment: Doh! *facepalm* Thanks, somehow I forgot that I had stumbled on that page before.